# Can't upload file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload an image in Laravel 5.

My environment is Windows.
I am using php artisan serve to run Laravel.

Error:

```
NotWritableException in Image.php line 143:
Can't write image data to path (D:\WORK\WebSite\iStore\public\assets/images/products/2015-07-05-08:52:33-6aa3df83gw1dtd5qki2oij.jpg)
```

Controller:

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . "-" . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('assets/images/products/' . $filename);

// echo dd(is_writable(public_path('assets/images/products')));

Image::make($image->getRealPath())-> resize(200, 200)-> save($path);

$product->image = 'assets/images/products/' . $filename;
```

I used dd(is_writable())to check permission, it is true.
And I also try 
`chmod 777 public/assets/images/products`

View:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/product/update', 'class' => '', 'files' => true)) !!}
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::Label('image', 'Product Image', array('sr-only')) !!}
<div>
{!! HTML::image($product->image, $product->title, array('class' => 'img-rounded', 'height' => '200')) !!}
</div>
<hr/>
{!! Form::file('image', array('class' => 'form-group')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What can I do with this error?

Comment: Does the folder `assets/images/products` exists and it is `writable` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes, it exists. And I tried chmod 777 with ConEmu, but I am in Windows. So I am not sure if it works correctly. dd(is_writable(public_path('assets/images/products'))); shows true.

Comment: If you are using linux, if got writable permission ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I also tried `cacls public/assets/images/products /g everyone:f`

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I try `$ CACLS public/assets/images/products` It shows `D:\WORK\WebSite\iStore\public\assets\images\products Everyone:(OI)(CI)F`

Comment: Ah, the problem is in the file name, It should not have `:` symbol. So, can you replace the `:` in the time format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Folder you mentioned i.e., `assets/images/products/` exists and it has writable permission

Make sure that you have a good file name i.e., it should not contain `:` symbol

So you shall change you code like this

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s')."-". $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('assets/images/products/'.$filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())-> resize(200, 200)-> save($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem might lie with the fact that you are using reserved characters within your file name. In Windows you cannot use colons `:` in file names. So you might want to replace the colons with dashes or something else, maybe like so:

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . "-" . $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

If readability is not a requirement here, and you're using the date and time to create unique filenames, you could just prepend a UNIX timestamp to the filename:

```
$filename = time() . "-" . $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

You might want to read the [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) documentation on MSDN for more information about the subject.

Comment: The reason you said is correct. Windows cannot use colons in file name. And it works. Thanks very much~